# How do I instrument test runners in SUnit?

Tags: unit-testing, smalltalk, pharo

I would like to instrument SUnit tests in [Pharo](http://pharo.org). What is the proper way to change how tests are run?

#### Example:

I want to introduce a timeout to tests, each test I run should be aborted after a given delay.

#### Problem:

SUnit does not feature a dedicated `TestRunner` in the model that would allow me to introduce changes easily. I can create a new subclass of `TestResult` and use the API there (`runCase:`, `addError:` ...) to get the enough control. However it feels strange to change the result class to modify the behavior on how tests are run.

I am used to [SMark](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/%7EStefanMarr/SMark) where I have a dedicated runner to modify these things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*DISCLAIMER*: I do not know what version of SUnit Pharo uses, so the concrete API may differ. Still, I hope this helps a bit.)

Subclassing `TestResult` is the way to go even though it may sound bit weird.

The general idea for customizing a new 'SUnit' instance is:

- for run-specific customization, do it in `TestResult` (namely `#runCase: aTestCase debugged: aBoolean`)
- for testcase-specific customization, do it in `TestCase` (namely `#performTest`)

I personally want to keep SUnit as simple as possible and here I see no reason for introducing a new class. Why? Look to recent changes in JUnit. :-) I do agree that SUnit deserves more documentation.

For examples how to implement timeout, skipping, etc., have a look at  [TestReport in Smalltalk/X](http://www.exept.de/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/stx/goodies/builder/reports/Builder__TestReport.st?view=markup%20%22TestReport%22%20from%20Smalltalk/X).

Comment: I'll dig into the Smalltalk/X version, Pharo's SUnit didn't change much I think.I did this approach and it works nicely if your tests that locally require special care. However if I want to do something global it doesn't work.

Comment: So yes, you do subclass `TestResult` to get custom behavior for me this still sounds wrong :), it's a result, it should not have anything to do with running :/. But Smalltalk/X has a much better protocol on Result `addError:detail:` and Co in Pharo are simply `addError:` so you miss half the information. I think I'll add that for pharo.